# OpenStack API Access over secondary ethernet connection or NIC

Tags: networking, openstack

I am trying to configure my server to utilize a secondary NIC card. I want the server to publish API access on both NICs at the same time. See the attached picture for a configuration diagram that shows that each server has two NICs, one configured with Internet access and the other wired to another server through a network switch.

[image: Shows the network configuration of my machines.]
How do I make OpenStack utilize both NICs at the same time?

I've seen the multi-nic feature in OpenStack, but that seems to link OpenStack Networks together, not physical NICs. Another option I've looked into is using the routing tables, but I don't know if this is possible/best practice.

Thanks,

Taylor

Answer (score 0):

There are many layers to that question :

- How did you deploy Openstack? This will heavily influence the flexibility you have the expose API access.
- I assume you mean the Openstack API (nova,neutron,keystone,cinder) itself?

Usually, the core API services are listening on your internal networks only.